Mongo database imported at image build, deleted when deployed
I am deploying a MongoDB image, and I want to make a custom image so that it has some data pre-imported. When I build the image, it shows that the files have been correctly imported:

> docker build -t mongoibdn -f mongodocker/Dockerfile .
...
Step 10/11 : RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db &&     dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:27017 -timeout 30s &&     ./resources/import_distances.sh
 ---> Running in f526a3759508
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 9
child process started successfully, parent exiting
2024/05/28 23:48:25 Waiting for: tcp://localhost:27017
2024/05/28 23:48:25 Connected to tcp://localhost:27017
2024-05-28T23:48:25.537+0000    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2024-05-28T23:48:25.597+0000    4696 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
[ 'Origin_1_Dest_1' ]
{
  _id: ObjectId('66566d491fd79c28cafda03f'),
  Origin: 'GST',
  Dest: 'JNU',
  Distance: 41
}
Removing intermediate container f526a3759508
 ---> 0ee667e0f8f2
Step 11/11 : EXPOSE 27017
 ---> Running in 9b2daad9cf3c
Removing intermediate container 9b2daad9cf3c
 ---> aaba8043bc65
Successfully built aaba8043bc65
Successfully tagged mongoibdn:latest

The script import_distances.sh is:
#!/bin/bash

# Import our enriched airline data as the 'airlines' collection
mongoimport -d agile_data_science -c origin_dest_distances --file data/origin_dest_distances.jsonl
mongosh agile_data_science --eval 'db.origin_dest_distances.ensureIndex({Origin: 1, Dest: 1})'
mongosh agile_data_science --eval 'printjson(db.origin_dest_distances.findOne())'

However, when I deploy said image:
...
mongo:
    image: mongoibdn
    container_name: mongotainer
    networks:
      - app-tier
    restart: always
    environment:
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: agile_data_science
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/pcreativa/data
...

And enter mongosh to see whether the data is there:
user@userr:~/path$ docker exec -it mongotainer mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 66566d638aa9b64adf2202d7
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.2.5
Using MongoDB:      6.0.15
Using Mongosh:      2.2.5

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/


To help improve our products, anonymous usage data is collected and sent to MongoDB periodically (https://www.mongodb.com/legal/privacy-policy).
You can opt-out by running the disableTelemetry() command.

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   2024-05-28T23:48:44.317+00:00: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
   2024-05-28T23:48:44.434+00:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
   2024-05-28T23:48:44.434+00:00: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never' in this binary version
   2024-05-28T23:48:44.434+00:00: vm.max_map_count is too low
------

test> show dbs
admin    8.00 KiB
config  12.00 KiB
local    8.00 KiB

As you see, the db "agile_data_science" isn't there. There has been times where the data was there, but it happens seemingly randomly.
Please help me with this as I really do not know what is causing this isuee.
I have tried to substitue the RUN with a CMD so that the import happens when the service is deployed, and not when the image is being built. This didn't work.

Are you building your image FROM the mongo image?  That's configured with a VOLUME so that you can't create an image with preloaded data.

@DavidMaze
yes:
...
FROM mongo:6.0
...
How do I bypass that restriction? Many thanks

Does How do I seed a mongo database using docker-compose? match what you're trying to do?  Most of the answers to that question use a separate container to load the initial data.  (That could even be part of your application container in an entrypoint wrapper script.)

Thank you so much for your answer. I created a .js script and added it to the entrypoint so that it executes after mongod is run. Been trying for days and this worked!!
